# Why are my passive checks not processed?

Tags: nagios

I have the following service configuration to capture SNMP traps:

```
define service {
    name                            SNMP_TRAP
    service_description             SNMP_TRAP
    active_checks_enabled           1       ; Active service checks are enabled
    passive_checks_enabled          1       ; Passive service checks are enabled/accepted
    parallelize_check               1       ; Active service checks should be parallelized
    process_perf_data               0
    obsess_over_service             0       ; We should obsess over this service (if necessary)
    check_freshness                 0       ; Default is to NOT check service 'freshness'
    notifications_enabled           1       ; Service notifications are enabled
    event_handler_enabled           1       ; Service event handler is enabled
    flap_detection_enabled          1       ; Flap detection is enabled
    process_perf_data               1       ; Process performance data
    retain_status_information       1       ; Retain status information across program restarts
    retain_nonstatus_information    1       ; Retain non-status information across program restarts
    check_command                   check-host-alive      ; This will be used to reset the service to "OK"
    is_volatile                     1
    check_period                    24x7
    max_check_attempts              1
    normal_check_interval           1
    retry_check_interval            1
    notification_interval           120
    notification_period             24x7
    notification_options            w,u,c,r
    contact_groups                  admins
    register                        0
}

define service {
    use                     SNMP_TRAP
    service_description     gigabitethernet16
    hostgroup_name          cisco
    check_interval          120
}
```

I have several devices in the `cisco` group, for example:

```
define host {
    use                     base-host
    host_name               cisco-sg300-28-4
    alias                   CISCO-SG300-28 (VT-Registratur)
    display_name            Switch VT-Registratur
    address                 10.0.1.109
    hostgroups              switches,cisco,cisco28
}
```

The service appears just fine in the web interface:

[image]

However, the received service checks are not processed at all. My `/var/lib/nagios3/rw/nagios.cmd` file collects the results, but the file is never cleared and the results don't appear in Nagios. `nagios.cmd` contains, for example:

```
[1437659629] PROCESS_SERVICE_CHECK_RESULT;cisco-sg300-28-4;gigabitethernet16;2;gigabitethernet16 linkDown
```

`accept_passive_service_checks` is enabled in `nagios.cfg`.

After further inspection, I realized that `nagios.cmd` is *supposed* to be a named pipe. In my case, it's a just a plain old file:

[image]

From our log archive, I can see that passive checks were processed at some point in the past, but now they're no longer working.

Comment: fwiw, "normal_check_interval" and "retry_check_interval" are version 2 syntax.

Comment: What does the nagios log say about this?

Comment: @Keith: I'm running with the highest log level output and I don't see anything relating to those service checks in the debug log. The "normal" log only lists the `CURRENT SERVICE STATE` after log rotation.

Comment: What are you using for trap handling? snmptt?

Comment: @Keith: I'm using [my own handler](https://github.com/oliversalzburg/node-nagios/blob/master/lib/traphandler.js), but I also used snmptt before. With identical results. I initially followed http://askaralikhan.blogspot.de/2010/12/receiving-snmp-traps-in-nagios.html and traps were visible in Nagios. I then started extending the concept and adding my own code, now nothing works :P

Comment: This is a wild guess but can you have parentheses in the alias? How many connections are open on the Nagios box (is there something holding the nagios listener open waiting for a connection)?

Comment: @TheFiddlerWins I assume the parens are fine, because active checks work. How can I check the connections?

Comment: Just thinking netstat/lsof

Comment: What are the perms for the /var/lib/nagios3/rw/ directory? Does nagios/httpd have the right to delete it?

Comment: The directory is owned by `nagios:nagios`. When the `nagios.cmd` is written (it gets removed when I restart Nagios), it will be owned by `root:root`. I already tried changing the ownership to `nagios:nagios` after it is created, but that has no effect on the issue.

Comment: `netstat|wc -l` gives 33. I don't think that's too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking at the configuration again to find more details for `nagios.cmd` and found this:

```
# EXTERNAL COMMAND FILE
# This is the file that Nagios checks for external command requests.
# It is also where the command CGI will write commands that are submitted
# by users, so it must be writeable by the user that the web server
# is running as (usually 'nobody').  Permissions should be set at the
# directory level instead of on the file, as the file is deleted every
# time its contents are processed.
# Debian Users: In case you didn't read README.Debian yet, _NOW_ is the
# time to do it.

command_file=/var/lib/nagios3/rw/nagios.cmd
```

So, that gave me the idea to look at `README.Debian`, which is located at `/usr/share/doc/nagios3-common/README.Debian` and contains the following instruction:

```
- activate external command checks in the nagios configuration. this
  can be done by setting check_external_commands=1 in the file
  /etc/nagios3/nagios.cfg.
```

While I was sure that this directive is enabled, I double-checked and it actually *wasn't* enabled.

After enabling it (and performing the other tasks mentioned in the `README`, the named pipe was created.